# How to retrieve all existing long-running conversations in Weld?

Tags: cdi, seam3, conversation-scope, weld

I'm writing application in JBoss 7.1.1.Final, Weld, Seam 3. I have following bean:

```
@ConversationScoped
public class ConversationBean implements Serializable {

   @Inject
   Conversation conversation;

   private Article article;
...
}
```

Now, the user might create multiple conversations, each conversation will be associated with the instance of ConversationBean. I need to be able to get all those instances that are associated with long-running conversation.

The reason why I need an access to them is that if a user opens one Article multiple times (thus he will create multiple conversations with the same article). If he changes the Article in one conversation, I want to be able to refresh the Articles in the other conversations.

Is there some standard way to do this?

Edit: "article" instance is looked up by entityManager and is managed within conversation. Entity manager is retrieved using Seam Managed Persistence Context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per session there's only ever one conversation going on. Injection Conversation will give you the one long-running conversation (or temporary conversation if it hasn't been promoted) going on).

Answer (score 0):

see http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/contexts.html

```
@Inject @Http private HttpConversationContext conversationContext;

[...]    

     conversationContext.getConversations()
```